# Detect if webView has loaded 50%

Tags: android, webview

how do i detect if my webview has loaded 50% of the page? i basically want to finish page loading after this point. here is my snippet but it loads the full page instead.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);// Enable Cookies
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);// Enable Java Script
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.afreesms.com/freesms/"); // Set Home page
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 50) {
                webView.stopLoading();
                // do screenshot
            }
        }
    }

    class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {

            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You might try try changing `if (progress == 50)` to `if (progress >= 50)`. The `onProgressChanged()` method might never be called at exactly 50%.

Comment: Yeah, everything else seems cool. Are you having another problem?

Comment: Ah. I was wondering why you wanted to stop it halfway through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement is checking for a `progress` of exactly `50`. The `onProgressChanged()` method might not ever get called at exactly 50%. Change your `if` clause to check for a `progress` greater than or equal to `50`:

```
if (progress >= 50) {
    webView.stopLoading();
    // do screenshot
}
```